# oracle jdbc driver version madness

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ora-01722

Why the heck does Oracle offer a different(!) version of the JDBC driver, e.g. ojdbc14.jar, for every(!) database version?
The files all have different sizes and thus probably different content.

background:
We get a random and seemingly irreproducible error saying "invalid number" when saving data (we guess it's the Timestamp). But it's not any particular statement. Most of the time, it saves just fine. Just once a month a harmless looking statement will fail.

So i had a closer look at Oracle's download site and noticed that none of the filesizes match despite files sharing the same name.

Our product is run on databases maintained by our clients, i.e. whatever version and patch the clients have running is what it is.
So what driver do we use? The latest (Oracle 11g) - despite the fact that it's usually <strike>9i and</strike> 10g databases?

Why don't they just link all versions to the same "one driver suits all" file?
Or are there minute differences leading to effects like our random errors?

EDIT: i was mistaken about the 9i databases.

Comment: The "version" in the driver's filename refers to the **Java version** they are intended for, not to the driver's version. I made it a habit to save the jar file with the driver's version appended when downloading them e.g. `ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar`. Just go for the latest drivers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

please see the compatibility matrix at
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-926E5324-D89A-4A00-B1AE-975C1089F0EA

Also take in mind that the timestamp datatype is only available since Oracle 10.

Comment: These drivers "can talk to" just about any modern database version. So you're saying i just pick the newest release and keep my fingers crossed that it has all the bug fixes i need?
... and i was wrong about the 9i's. We retired them last year.

Comment: well, i doubt it is a bug in the jdbc driver. i would inspect the code for number casting bugs, "number to string", "string to date" and so on. Are we talking about ORA-01722, invalid number? If so, i would check the debugging logs and not care about driver version conflicts.

Comment: Yes, it's ORA-01722. We use PreparedStatements, meaning the type conversions are all done by the driver. And the same statement works fine 99.9% of the time. We of course looked at our code first, but there seems to be nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Random `ORA-01722` errors are very often caused by relying on *implicit* data type casting. Don't do it. Pass the right values/objects and do never rely on implict casting. Even different NLS settings can cause this error (so it might work on System A, but not on System B)

Answer (score 15):

The numbers in ojdbc14.jar, ojdbc5.jar, ojdbc6.jar, ojdbc7.jar and ojdbc8.jar refer to the version of the Java compiler that was used. With every version of Java come new JDBC APIs so these numbers are useful to know what to expect. For example in Java 8, there is a new method `executeLargeUpdate` in `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. This method will be implemented in ojdbc8.jar but not in ojdbc7.jar. Also if your runtime uses Java 7 then you know you can't use ojdbc8.jar otherwise you'll run into a `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` error. These are the reasons why Oracle includes these numbers in the jar's name. Also note that if you want to know from which Oracle Database release the jar comes from you can run `java -jar ojdbc8.jar`. Both the Database and the driver are backward compatible (up to 1 major release) so, even though it's recommended, you don't have to use the same version of the product on both tiers.

Comment: with which java compiler does ojdbc14 jar gets compiled?

Comment: With the compiler from JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 4):

When we upgraded our Oracle database from 8.1.7 to 10.2.0, I was able to use the same Oracle jdbc driver (ojdbc14.jar). So their jdbc driver supports quite a few versions at the same time. Of course it's possible that some of the drivers are buggy, but the plan is to support more versions at the same time.