# Oracle product version and jdbc driver version?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am using oracle db and the RDBMS product version is : DatabaseProductVersion: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

If I connect this db instance with an older but supported jdbc driver version say 10.1, will there be any performance problems (say 5000 transactions per second)?

> Is it a best practice that the product version and jdbc version
>   should match ?

I could not find a satisfying document related with this issue. So I wanted to ask it to the big guys thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation from Oracle is located at

- [Oracle® JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#02_02) under Which JDBC drivers support which versions of Oracle Database?
- [Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/overvw.htm) under the heading Feature List.

You have two questions, the first is will you have any performance problems because of using the older JDBC driver ?

The second is should the version of the JDBC driver match the version of the database as a best practice.

I don't know your workload, but any performance problems regarding using the JDBC driver with be related to how you use it more than its specific version. Answering the question of how to do I use Oracle's JDBC drivers in an optimal performing way is a seperate question which depends on your workload.

For documentation regarding that see [Java Programming with Oracle JDBC Chapter 19](http://oreilly.com/catalog/jorajdbc/chapter/ch19.html) which gives an example of how the features and which client (OCI or Thin) you use has more impact on performance than JDBC driver version.

Also see [High-Performance Oracle JDBC Programming](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-oracle-jdbc-090470.html) and [Expert Oracle JDBC Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059407X) for more information that demonstrates that how you use the features in the driver for performance should influence which JDBC standard you need to use and which driver version supports that standard.

Regarding the second question, the number 5 worst practice is listed as **5. Do not use old versions of the drivers – the 10gR2 drivers are supported with the 8i database!!** at [Worst practices when using Oracle JDBC Drivers – great presentation by Douglas Surber](http://technology.amis.nl/2006/10/25/worst-practices-when-using-oracle-jdbc-drivers/). Douglas Surber is listed as the principal developer for Oracle JDBC Drivers.

Which leads me to believe the best practice is always using the latest JDBC version that supports your database, unless you have specific issues preventing you from doing so however if you really need official evidence and in person verification of this rather than my word for it, feel free to contact [Douglas Surber](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DouglasSurber).

A related SO question is [Oracle JDBC driver version madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756208/oracle-jdbc-driver-version-madness).

Comment: Very nice information. Thank you very much. It can give me some boosts to have deeper knowledge about jdbc.