# How to setup multiple datasources with different versions of the same jdbc driver?

Tags: java, database, oracle, tomcat, datasource

I have to deploy to tomcat7 server, an application that connect to two databases:

- Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 which need the ojdbc7.jar
- Oracle Database 11.2.0.4 which uses ojdbc6.jar

[image]

I created two datasources that uses the same class from both libs, now I need to copy libs into $CATALINA_HOME/lib, I fear ending up with calssloader conflit as the two jars share many classes with same className.

```
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
```

How to deal with that ?

Comment: "Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1) JDBC drivers are certified with supported Oracle Database releases (11.x.0.x). However, they are not certified to work with older, unsupported database releases, such as 10.2.x, 10.1.x, 9.2.x, and 9.0.1.x." https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/getsta.htm#JJDBC20000

Comment: independently from databases versions (assuming I have 2 db with no commun compatible driver) is it ever possible to have 2 datasources for them ?

Comment: I think it would be hard with a single web app. You could have two web apps with the driver in their WEB-INF/lib directories, or create OSGi bundles perhaps.

Comment: Generally the drivers are [supposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756208/oracle-jdbc-driver-version-madness) to be backwards compatible, even if they may not be *certified* to be. Almost everything is possible, and having two datasources with different version drivers isn't nearly the worst thing you could imagine trying to get to work, but I wouldn't try to solve it in code as the first step.